# How to solve this component based events response issue?

Tags: architecture, component-based, events

I'm working on a new game architecture and I have issues with the handling of events in our component-based approach.

We have a component *Match*. When a match ends, an event *Match_end* is sent. There are two components that are listening to this event, *Ads* and *Store*.

The behaviour that we'd like is the following: when the match ends, an ad is displayed, and when it's closed (or if it's not available), the store is displayed.

With the current setup of events and listeners, both the *Ads* and the *Store* will be displayed simultaneously.

We're thinking about specifying some order on subscribing (but it looks wrong to me).

Who should resolve the event processing order? Is it *Nobody* and we should use an other approach?

Comment: Should these really be the same event, even? It sounds like you want a state machine that goes from Match state to Try-Show-Ad state to Store state as two distinct transitions, not a queue of transitions firing off simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here and its really a matter of taste.

**Multiple Listeners - Ordered Invocation**

As you mentioned, you could specify some *order* that defines how the listeners are to be invoked when the event is raised.  Generally speaking, I've almost always see the listener expose some numeric value to determine its placement.  Sometimes systems expose a set of constants that dictate magic values to represent specific points in the list such as `START`, `END`, or `AFTER_SYSTEM`.

Then it is the responsibility of the subject the listeners are registered with to read and adhere to the specified order in a deterministic way.  Then its just the normal listener dispatch by looping over an already pre-sorted list and invoke the listeners one-by-one.

**Single Listener Dispatch**

Another solution would be that your system only allows the registration of a single `Match_End` handler of which you then manually compose the dispatch order yourself in code.

Answer (score 0):

Add another event.

1. Register only *Ads* to listen to *Match_end*.
2. Register *Store* to listen to *Ads_end*.

Then, when the match ends, *Match_end* is sent; then *Ads* take over, which sends *Ads_end* when the add is closed or when it realizes it can't be displayed; then *Store* takes over.